# Possibility for fstring-like code in C++ using meta-programming

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, f-string, stdformat

The introduction of `std::format` into C++20 is very nice and can even be used (from `fmtlib` itself) in iterations *before* C++20. It certainly allows for less verbose code than the `iostream` equivalent code that came before it.

Contrast, for example, the following two statements where the latter seems clearer and more succinct (to me, anyway):

```cpp
std::cout << "Your name is " << name << " and your licence number is "
    << std::setw(9) << std:setfill('0') << num << ".\n";
fmt::print("Your name is {} and your licence number is {:09}.\n", name, num);
```

However, the `iostream` method still has *one* small advantage in that the things that are to be printed are in the sequence in which they're listed, so you can read them from left to right. Well, provided you can ignore all the "noise" in the statement (`<<`, `setw`, and the like) :-)

In other words, you don't really have to look (too far) ahead to the arguments to see what's being printed.

In that sense, `std::format` is more like Python's `str.format()` (and C's `printf`) method as they both list a format string with special markers (like `{}` or `%09d`), followed by arguments which are slotted in to where those markers are.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to use C++'s recent meta-programming features to provide *true* f-strings, something like Python's:

```py
print("Your name is {name} and your licence number is {licence_num:09}.\n");
```

This inlining of the expressions to output would be much easier to read in the code. I know rather little of the code generation capabilities of C++20, so I wonder if it's plausible to take a statement like that above and generate a new statement in the "accepted" form.

This would be done as part of the compilation process itself (not some pre-processing tool that likely introduces extra opportunity for problems). That way, you would never actually *see* the modified line, it would just magically be made from the more readable form, compiled, and thrown away.

In other words, an expression such as:

```cpp
magic::fstring("Your name is {name} and your licence number is {num:09}.\n");
```

would become this for compilation:

```cpp
fmt::format("Your name is {} and your licence number is {:09}.\n", name, num);
```

I've read the Sutton and Childers P1717R0 "Compile-time Metaprogramming in C++" document and tried to do some other research, but I'm not entirely sure that the `consteval` and `meta` things provide enough power to break apart a string like that above at compile time.

Can anyone more knowledgeable about these features in C++20 indicate whether this would be a viable approach and, if so, how it would be done?

Or, alternatively, there may be *another* way of doing this, I'd be grateful for any suggestions on that front.

Comment: To be able to read from left to right you can just use the named arguments and give them some reasonable name, preferably the same as the variable name itself if namespace is not involved. This works for your simple `"Your name is {name} and your licence number is {num:09}"` case. See https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#named-arguments for examples.

Comment: it's possible to define interpolated formatting: `my::print("%d", 1, "%s", "hello");` but commas can't be removed.

Comment: Now after reading it the second time I think maybe OP is interested in a solution using the `meta::` as illustrated in P1717, instead of just using what is available in the current standards.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: yes. From that document, it looks like it's (or it will be, since I had not realised that was as yet un-standardised) possible to modify arbitrary characters within the compiler stream, effectively rewriting the code on the fly, with code.

Comment: There has been quite some buzz about this topic just 2 weeks ago in the [std-proposals mailing list](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2023/10/subject.php).

Comment: If you wish to do something experimental, you can pluck `m4` or `sed` as a preprocessor with gcc, and transform `f".... { anything } ...."` into `".... {} ....", anything`. This works pretty well, however you require another preprocessor pass to do it.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is fundamentally impossible. There is no way to reference an entity by its name from a string value, not even at compile-time.

There is currently no reflection support in C++ that would allow for this. The paper you refer to is a proposal that hasn't made it into the standard. There seemed to have been a stall in work on reflection support for a while, but just recently there was a paper [P2996](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2996r0.html) targeting C++26, although I think what it proposes would still not allow for what you are asking for here.

There has also been an initial paper [P1819](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/588) which specifically adds support for this behavior in string literals without depending on reflection and code synthesis support. However, it hasn't seen any progress in the last year and it is currently up to the paper's author to present a proposal based on the feedback.

---

To clarify:

If the functionality in P1717 was added to C++20, then it would probably allow for what you want, although I haven't verified this. However, P1717 is just a proposal that never was incorporated into a standard.

There is a also a TR "Extensions for reflection" (ISO/IEC TS 23619:2021) which extends C++20, but it follows a different approach to reflection than P1717 and I haven't checked whether it would allow to implement what you want, but I think it did not because it lacks code synthesis.

Comment: *No, this is fundamentally impossible.* I don’t think so. Maybe it might not be achieved exactly like the OP described but it is still possible if it means by [parsing the string at runtime just like Python does](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#abstract). [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html#overview) is just one library that gets close to Python string formatting API. [Inja](https://pantor.github.io/inja/) does exactly what the OP describes but it does it using key - value pairs to format strings. I know it uses [nlohmann’s json for modern c++ library.](https://pantor.github.io/inja/)

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon: The limitation is that C++ language doesn't have something to map string to variables. transforming `magic::fstring("Your name is {name})` into `fmt::format("Your name is {}, map["name"])` would be possible through.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I am talking specifically about the syntax that OP wants. The point of it is to _not_ have to provide the variables as argument or in some external mapping, but to have the compiler evaluate the variable in the caller's context from its name in the string. That part is impossible in current C++.

Comment: @Jarod42: "The limitation is that C++ language doesn't have something to map string to variables"  Umm, `unqualid`, described in the P1717R0 linked in the question?

Comment: @BenVoigt P1717 hasn't made it into C++ and it doesn't look like it will any time soon (at least completely).

Comment: @user17732522: Nonetheless, my interpretation of the question is whether this could be done using the facilities of P1717R0

Comment: I still don’t think **Fundamentally impossible** should be used here. It is just extreme. I remember when C++11 added [raw strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), we thought it was impossible but it is now aye? Formatted strings can be achieved too like in Python where once the interpreter encounters a named variable within `{}` in an `f string`, it looks for the variable in all available scope and concatenates the aforementioned variable in the `f string` if it is string convertible. Can it be done in C++? It’s only a matter of time finding an efficient solution

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Of course it is possible if you modify the language. But it is fundamentally impossibly in the bounds of the current language, because its core completely lacks necessary primitives.

Comment: @user17732522 yes **its core completely lacks  necessary primitives**. That’s why such addition will use inefficient work arounds to achieve. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is not possible without a change to the language itself, but how about something like this:

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

template <class... Args>
auto fstring(Args&&... args) {
    std::string str;
    (fmt::format_to(back_inserter(str), "{}", std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    return str;
}

int main() {
    auto const name = "Foo Bar";
    auto const age = 24;

    std::cout << fstring("My name is ", name, " and I am ", fmt::format("{:#x}", age), " years old\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do in C++23 without hacks such as a custom preprocessor. There are two proposals to add string interpolation to C++:

- [P1819 Interpolated Literals](https://wg21.link/P1819)
- [String Interpolation and F-strings for C++](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadrielk/cpp-proposals/main/f-string/f-string-r2.bs) (not published yet)

So it might be added in future versions of the standard.

[fstrings in Rust](https://docs.rs/fstrings/latest/fstrings/) show that at least some limited form of interpolation using metaprogramming is possible in principle. But not with what we have now in the standard and not even with [P2996](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2996r0.html) which is the most promising reflection proposal at the moment.

Comment: The interpolated literals seems interesting but I'm not sure if some simple syntactic sugar in the compiler (like `x[7]` being the same as `*(x+7)`) wouldn't be easier. In other words, the compiler turns `f"My name/age is {name}/{me.get_age():2}"` into `std::format("My name/age is {}/{:2}", name, me.get_age())` (and *possibly* brings in the required header) under the covers. That should basically work in every case